Creating first Turbo Repo package for a logger failing to import
I am working to setup my first Turbo Repo project using a mix of Next for the UI and Express for the API. I am trying to create a logging package I can include in the API app but also eventually the worker app as well.
I have however run into an issue where it says it is unable to find it or that itr is the wrong module type.
The error message I am seeing is
 The current file is a CommonJS module whose imports will produce 'require' calls; however, the referenced file is an ECMAScript module and cannot be imported with 'require'. Consider writing a dynamic 'import("@repo/logger")' call instead.
api:build:   To convert this file to an ECMAScript module, change its file extension to '.mts', or add the field `"type": "module"` to '/Users/me/projects/turbo-new/apps/api/package.json'.
api:build: 
api:build: 7 import { logger } from "@repo/logger";

Below is the full files of the code that might be useful
Directory: packages/logger
tsconfig.json
{
  "extends": "@repo/typescript-config/base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}


package.json
{
  "name": "@repo/logger",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc --watch",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./src/logger.ts",
      "default": "./dist/logger.js"
    }
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@repo/typescript-config": "*",
    "typescript": "latest"
  }
}

src/logger.ts
// Packages
import * as winston from "winston";

export const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || "info",
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [new winston.transports.Console()],
});

Directory: apps/api
package.json
{
  "name": "api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.17.0",
    "@repo/logger": "*",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.12",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "prisma": "^5.17.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.5.4"
  }
}

src/index.ts
// src/index.ts
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";

dotenv.config();

import { logger } from "@repo/logger";

const app: Express = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  logger.info("Hello world");

  res.send("Express + TypeScript Server");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`[server]: Server is running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});


Have you tried adding "type": "module"?
